# Use of Preposition

Tags: prepositions

What preposition is correct to be put into the following sentence?
They still had some confusion------ the agreement.
a) about     b)over       c)in    d) of

I think the correct one is "over".

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate why you think it's *over* and not any of the others. What research have you done (eg collocations for "confusion *preposition noun*)?

Comment: I have made use of intuition. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Isn't it all about the context and perception? around, with... A few more can be used. Depth of the context gives a better idea.

Comment: We don't know the *exact* context, but I probably wouldn't use any of OP's suggested prepositions - alternatives such as ***regarding*** or ***concerning*** would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm with FF here. On ELU, this might be regarded as closable on only allowing sub-optimal answers. _In_ and _of_ are obviously incorrect here, an argument might possibly be made for _over_, and _about_ is perhaps acceptable. But _regarding_ and _concerning_ are certainly preferable.

Answer (score 1):

> They still had some confusion about the agreement.

They're trying to find out what the agreement means.

> They still had some confusion over the agreement.

They're trying to create an agreement, or the agreement is something that's needed for them to move forward.

> They still had some confusion in the agreement.

Either "agreement" is an event that they were are part of and confusion occurred during this event, or "agreement" is something they are fixing (removing confusion) and they haven't completed doing that.

> They still had some confusion of the agreement.

They don't know which agreement they want to select.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that the answer is b, as it makes the most grammatical sense.

Comment: This was downvoted on ELU as being mere opinion (lacking research), confusing grammar with idiomaticity, and probably being a different opinion to that of many